# add documents to data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of trainings with the associated documents and dates.
I want to add documents to these trainings without creating duplicates in my database.

i.e. if I have a training named  A, with the date and I want to add a document to it , I will get

[image]

The code Ive written gives me this

[image]

The code:

```
Private Sub Sub_Ajout_Mdp_Forma_Click()
    If mode_edition = True Then
        If Me.ListBox_Form_Intern.ListIndex = -1 Then
            MsgBox ("Pour ajouter le mode de preuve veuillez choisir une formation")
        Else
            Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Personne)
            Nom_Forma = Me.ListBox_Form_Intern.List(Me.ListBox_Form_Intern.ListIndex, 0)
            Date_Forma = Me.ListBox_Form_Intern.List(Me.ListBox_Form_Intern.ListIndex, 1)
            Fin_Col_Forma = ws.Cells(10, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Dim plage As Range
            Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Personne)
            Set plage = ws.Rows(10)
            Set Trouve = plage.Cells.Find(what:=Nom_Forma)
            If Trouve Is Nothing Then
            Else
                If MsgBox("la formation existe déjà, Voulez vous l'écraser pour ajouter le mode de preuve?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton2, "Titre") = vbYes Then
                    ws.Cells(10, Fin_Col_Forma).Value = Nom_Forma
                    Cells(10, Fin_Col_Forma).Select
                    ws.Activate
                    ws.Cells(11, Fin_Col_Forma).Value = CDate(Date_Forma)
                    repertoire = Application.GetOpenFilename()
                    ws.Cells(12, Fin_Col_Forma) = repertoire
                Else
                    MsgBox (" Vous n'avez pas les droits requis")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to add documents without creating duplicates, so delete the old training and keep only what I've added

Comment: Change `Fin_Col_Forma` to `Trouve.Column` in the `Else` part of your `If Trouve Is Nothing Then` condition. That should resolve your issue. More importantly, 1. Please use `Option Explicit`, 2. Please declare your variable even if you want to set them as `Variant` type, 3. Please do not use things like `Activate`, `Select`, 4. Always qualify your object. `ActiveWorkbook` can and has caused many problems.. just some hints for you

Comment: @Zac thank you very much, Ive replaced Fin_Col_Forma by Trouve.column and its working as I wanted. Thanks again